# How Youtube changes the `referer` header?

Tags: http, http-referer

In this page of the Youtube all `referer` headers are set to `http://youtube.com` although the page url is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL6If0ZXsBk

See this picture for instance: [image: screenshot]

I want to know how Youtube changes the `referer` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the following meta tag :

`<meta content="origin" name="referrer">`

See https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/21/meta-referrer/ for more info. :)